# implementing VCS on an existing web portal

Tags: git, web, version-control, portal

My university's got a [web portal](http://rggu.com/). There are many pages of different kinds maintained by many different people. I want to implement a kind of VCS system on it, so that the administrator could see pages being changed, deleted or added. The problem is, being a student I most probably won't get access to the servers and file system. Well even if I did, it's  important that users do not notice any difference (or the interface should be really friendly to non-professionals).

The way I see a solution is to make a small web crawler that would go through each internal link and write down everything it sees. And then to implement a git on the database, for example.

Well guys I'd appreciate any ideas on this.

Answer (score 1):

Before speaking from a technical point of view, I guess you should ask yourself: for who are you solving a problem?

- Is it just because it sounds fun to implement this kind of solution?
- Will it only impact a few students?
- Will it also help your university staff?

My guess is that your university don't want a crappy portal. So they don't want a tool hard to use (and easy to mess up with). And so they might want to help you improve it.

Consequently, even if you're a student, it might pay to try to work hand in hand with your university staff / sysadmin.

At first it might be more complicate than just implemented a crawler by your own. Because you will have dependencies on other people (who might not have the same point of view). And because sometimes people are resistant to change.

However if you can work hand in hand with your sysadmin, you could use an appropriate tool and avoid reinventing the wheel. (I guess nowadays every decent CMS has all the features you want: keep an historic, notify watchers, intuitive to non technical persons, ...).

My advice would be: start doing a bit of state-of-the-art study. Find promising tools. Weight the pros (of having a relevant tool) and the cons (eg: migrating has a cost) from your point of view and from the point of view of your university staff. And go to your sysadmin to discuss this with them.

---

Now let's consider the case where you would have to handle a website on which there's absolutely no way you could get in touch with the admin. Then the only solution seems to be what you suggest: use a web crawler.

From a technical point of view you could for example:

- use [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to crawl the site (it has all the option you could dream of to follow url, retrieve images and documents, handling cookies if you need to authenticate, ...)
- copy this local copy in a git repo, and make a new commit every time you crawl the site
- Create a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to make a backup periodically

Whether you'd use the implementation or a modified version of it, the drawbacks I can think of are at least:

- Your sysadmin might not be very keen of having someone downloading the whole website periodically
- It wouldn't be easy to restore a backup anyway, since we're considering you don't have access to the portal backend or the database
- It would be even more work to have the other features you want (eg: letting users watch the changes)
- This tool will have a maintenance cost, because it will eventually break because of a reason we can't foresee today, and it will need to be fixed. Even if you're willing to pay this cost yourself, what will happen the day you'll leave your university?

Comment: Thanks a lot, @gturri, for such a detailed answer! Speaking of finding the relevant tools, I'm a bit lost here. I'll probably speak to the sysadmin first, find out what CMS is currently used and what plug-ins can be added, etc.. cause now I'm not quite sure what to look for. (That's why I created my post here in the first place)